# Record Nexus 10 screen

Tags: samsung-nexus-10, screencast

I am trying to find a way to record the screen on my Nexus 10 tablet.

I make promotional videos for my company to show off our cloud-based software. I need a good way to show people that mobile devices can be used to make great use of our software. We use Nexus because it has the NFC chip reader and writer.

Is there any way to do this that does not require rooting?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-other-android-related-questions) for details). You might want to check other [questions tagged screencast](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast), or see [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for other places where your question might be on topic.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more about a problem to be solved than an app to be found.

Comment: A tangential comment: the NFC chip in the Nexus 10 isn't the best. The Nexus 7 can read and write Mifare Classic tags as well, and can read IDs from many kinds of contactless payment card too. In addition, the lower-res screen of the Nexus 7 is more amenable to screencasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Nexus 10 should be able to upgrade to the newest Android 4.4 Kitkat any day now. It has a new option to record the screen, but you need to be/know someone who has basic knowledge about the Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-screen-recording

Since you did not accept an answer yet, hope this info still helps and I'm not necromancing your thread. ;)

Comment: I like this new guy! I suggest pointing out in your answer ([edit it](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/57079/edit)) with a bit more clarity that this will require you to have an ADB connection to your computer. Also, a note: When you see an old question with outdated answers, or missing recent information, posting an answer with updated info is [actually a good thing to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131495/how-to-handle-outdated-answers)!

Comment: Thanks for the info about kitkat. I am still looking for a solution where I don't have to root the device our buy more hardware like a new video card for my desktop.

Comment: @dotVezz: Thanks! :) I thought it might not be a wise idea to let someone without any SDK knowledge do this kind of stuff, so I tried to keep it understandable for devs, but not people unexperienced with the SDK (or any other ADB connection).

Comment: @user2126220: This does not require any rooting or new hardware, but it does require someone with some basic knowledge how to connect and interact with an Android device for the Android SDK (Software Development Kit). Hope you can find someone close by for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need your tablet it be rooted for this. After rooting use SCR screen recorder (preferably the pro version ) to record your screen. There are many apps available but I found this the best

Comment: thanks for this recommendation . i checked it and its a good one .

Answer (score 0):

You can always **use an app** such as [No Root Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.screenrecnoroot) to video record your screen. But the problem with this option is that you have to connect your device to a windows computer in order to capture.

If you're willing to use external hardware, one good option is an External HDMI capture card and a USB to HDMI cable.This way the recording does not affect the performance of your device or app. More expensive than an app on the device, but much more flexible.